# How to align two seperate <ul> classes next to each other in navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I need two separate lists in my NavBar, both aligned to the right of the company image, with one `<li>` more in the center. I have tried aligning right on both and using margins but it changes in looks (for the worst) when I resize the browser.

Am I going about it wrong? I have attached my HTML and CSS (I'm using bootstrap) below. How do I get my navbar to appear like the image?

```css
/* Navigation */
#menu.navbar-default {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0);
 height: 65px;
}

.navbarimg {
 position: absolute;
 left: 15%;
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.nav-stacked {
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
 color: #333333;
}

.nav-stacked li:hover {
 background-color: none;
}

.nielsennav {
 font-family: 'Knockout','Open sans', sans-serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header col-lg-12 col-md-12"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.nielsen.com/us/en.html"> <img src="img/navbargrey.png" alt="Nielsen" width="45" height="65" class="navbarimg"> </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  
        <li><a href="joincreate.html">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">    
        <li><a href="welcomenz.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="howitworks.html">How it works</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="joincreate.html">Join</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What I want to achieve:
[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: You’ve put them both in the same container, in the same column definition.  That’s a good place to start. What exactly are you looking for because there is an answer provided below that looks really similar to your picture you gave? I think it’s in your best interest to study more on bootstrap conventions. If your going to use bootstrap you might as well let it do all of the work for you instead of trying to add all the specific position styles your adding. Bootstrap can handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because absolute position in class `navbarimg`.

Remove `position: absolute;` from `navbarimg`

```css
/* Navigation */
#menu.navbar-default {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0);
 height: 65px;
}

.navbarimg {
 left: 15%;
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.nav-stacked {
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
 color: #333333;
}

.nav-stacked li:hover {
 background-color: none;
}

.nielsennav {
 font-family: 'Knockout','Open sans', sans-serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header col-lg-12 col-md-12"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.nielsen.com/us/en.html"> <img src="img/navbargrey.png" alt="Nielsen" width="45" height="65" class="navbarimg"> </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  
        <li><a href="joincreate.html">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">    
        <li><a href="welcomenz.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="howitworks.html">How it works</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="joincreate.html">Join</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the position absolute to position relative and created styles for nav and li with an inline-block to line it up with some positioning styles added. Hope it helps.

```css
/* Navigation */

.nav{
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 20%;
margin-top: -15px;
}
.nav-right{
right:10%;
}
li{
display:inline-block;

}

#menu.navbar-default {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0);
 height: 65px;
}

.navbarimg {
 position: relative;
 left: 15%;
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.nav-stacked {
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
 color: #333333;
}

.nav-stacked li:hover {
 background-color: none;
}

.nielsennav {
 font-family: 'Knockout','Open sans', sans-serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header col-lg-12 col-md-12"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.nielsen.com/us/en.html"> <img src="img/navbargrey.png" alt="Nielsen" width="45" height="65" class="navbarimg"> </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  
        <li><a href="joincreate.html">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">    
        <li><a href="welcomenz.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="howitworks.html">How it works</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="joincreate.html">Join</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This forced all my <li> elements up to the top of the page?

Comment: What is the desired results?  I thought you wanted the elements like the image you showed inline at the top?

Comment: I was aiming for my elemts to be vertically centered but horizontally aligned how the images showed

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. thanks

```css
/* Navigation 
#menu.navbar-default {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0);
 height: 65px;
}
/* 
.navbarimg {
 position: absolute;
 left: 15%;
 margin-top: -15px;
}
*/
.nav-stacked {
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
 color: #333333;
}

.nav-stacked li:hover {
 background-color: none;
}

.nielsennav {
 font-family: 'Knockout','Open sans', sans-serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #000;
}

.navbar-header{display:flex}
.nav.navbar-nav{flex-direction: row;}

a.navbar-brand{
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header col-lg-12 col-md-12"> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.nielsen.com/us/en.html"> <img src="img/navbargrey.png" alt="Nielsen" width="45" height="65" class="navbarimg"> </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  
        <li><a href="joincreate.html">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center ">    
        <li><a href="welcomenz.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="howitworks.html">How it works</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="joincreate.html">Join</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```